# Merge the True False Value based On Condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have df like this

```
    a      b      c            
0  True   False   True  
1  False  False   False 
2  True   True    True
```

i want this

```
     a      b      c     Result       
0  True   False   True   True
1  False  False   False  False
2  True   True    True   True
```

if any one Value True then Result True ele false

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any()`:

```
df['result']  = df.any(1) 

# or with pd.assign
df = df.assign(result = df.any(1))
```

both will print:

```
       a      b      c  result
0   True  False   True    True
1  False  False  False   False
2   True   True   True    True
```

Note that `1` is short for `axis=1`, i.e. perform operation row-wise

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` with `(axis=1)` to check the existance of any True in each row.

```
df['result'] = df.any(axis=1)
```

If values are string rather than boolean then:

```
df['result'] = df.eq('True').any(axis=1)
```

Comment: I believe specifying ```eq(True)``` might be redundant?

Answer (score 1):

**It's quite easy...**

```
if a or b or c:
    #do stuff
```

or you could also use

```
if a | b | c:
    #do stuff
```